# MVP's Model vs Interactor from Clean architecture

Tags: android, mvp, clean-architecture, android-mvp

I'm using `MVP` pattern in my apps and lately I've been reading about Clean Architecture. One thing I don't really understand is this : what's the difference between Model in `MVP` and `Interactor` ? My understanding is that an `Interactor` is just a special case of a `Model`. Instead of having a Model that handles a lot of use cases, we split each case in a separate class. Other than that you can obviously move all `Interactor`s in a separate module but in terms of code both classes are doing the same thing.

Am I right or am I missing some important point? Thanks

`tl;dr :` In other words `Model` in MVP is just a bunch of `Interactor`s ?

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that Model, Interactor, Business layer are names of the layer which provide data, I use the MVP architecture and prefer to call my Business Layer Interactor if it is going to call an API an Helper if it is going to use an Android API.

My suggestion is not to stick to the name and pick one and try to take care of MVP layer separations.

You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.